# Rendering one single Next.js component separately outside the Next.js framework context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

js and React experts,

Situation:

- In our portal we have 2 completely different applications: CMS (PHP based with its own framework, templating engine and so on) and an Online Shop (Next.js based, React technology stack).
- Now, there's one module which is already completely built in the Next.js world, but it doesn't exist in the CMS world.

Challenge:

- implement the same functionality also in the CMS part of the website with minimal possible effort

Obviously, the naive way would be just to implement it once again in the CMS technology, which is possible, but not very elegant, as the implementation in Next.js will be supported by a separate team, which is going to change things over time and add features, that all would need to be implemented twice.

I'm new to React, but according to an example from the official docs there is a way to run a React app encapsulated in one div element (see https://nextjs.org/learn/foundations/from-react-to-nextjs). I tried it and this minimal example worked embedded in the CMS templating context just fine.

Now, the question is: Would that also work with a Next.js component? Can I render the complete subpage with a separate CMS engine and **only one single encapsulated HTML element with Next.js**? From what I understood Next.js is built to take over the rendering of the whole page completely, but maybe there's some advanced way to make it work React-like?

Thank you very much for your input.